# Use external ip in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have been browsing looking and reading why my external ip is not resolving on Poc I am doing with Minikube .

I am running Minikube on a Ubuntu 16.04 distro.

When i do an http get at http://192.168.99.100:32431/ i get the nginx page.

Is there a why to use external ip with port 80 and not with Minikube ip and the port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am running Minikube on a Ubuntu 16.04 distro.

Minikube is not designed to have an "external ip", it's for simple development-time testing. One will observe it is not even using the [separate kubernetes binaries/containers](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/08-bootstrapping-kubernetes-controllers.md#download-and-install-the-kubernetes-controller-binaries) that one would expect in a for-real kubernetes deployment

> Is there a why to use external ip with port 80
>   and not with Minikube ip and the port ?

No to the second half of the question, but if you wish to have the Service listen on port 80 of the minikube VM, then a [NodePort Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) will very likely do that